# AJAX returning intended response but not HTML is not reflected

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

[image]I'm trying to place some HTML elements based on the returned response. While the response is returned, nothing is reflected. I tried = instead of == where the response is being compared, and while this returned a value that "Current Password is Incorrect", it did not change the value when the password WAS correct. I don't understand why this is the case. Can anyone help me understand why my code isn't working?

```
<!-- My Controller Code -->
    public function chkPassword(Request $request)
    {
        //$data = $request->all();
        $adminCount = Admin::where(['username' => Session::get('adminSession'), 'password' => md5($request->current_pwd), 'status' => 1])->count();
        if($adminCount == 1){
            echo 'true'; die;
        } else {
            echo 'false'; die;
        }
    }

<!-- My jQuery Code -->
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#current_pwd").keyup(function(){
            var current_pwd = $("#current_pwd").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '/admin/check-pwd',
                data: {current_pwd: current_pwd},
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(response) {
                    if(response == "false") {
                        $("#chkPwd").html("<font color='red'>Current Password is Incorrect</font>");
                    } else if (response == "true") {
                        $("#chkPwd").html("<font color='green'>Current Password is Correct</font>");
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

<!-- My web.php file -->
    Route::get('/admin/check-pwd', 'AdminController@chkPassword');
```

Comment: var current_pwd = $("#current_pwd").val();
$("#chkPwd").html('');

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand

Comment: below this line type

success: function(response) {
console.log(response) // new line

and share the snapshot of console

Comment: Ok I have just did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echoing like this in your controller code, You have to send it as json response to perform the match in your jquery

```
public function chkPassword(Request $request)
    {
        //$data = $request->all();
        $adminCount = Admin::where(['username' => Session::get('adminSession'), 'password' => md5($request->current_pwd), 'status' => 1])->count();
        if($adminCount == 1){
            return->response('true');
        } else {
            return->response('false');
        }
    }
```

And instead of `$('#chkpwd').html` use `$('#chkpwd').append()`

Try this, It'll work

Comment: return response()->json(['success':true]);